# Unable to import ShadowJar plugin for Gradle in Intellij

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-plugin, shadowjar

I'm trying to set up the shadow jar plugin for use in my Gradle project.  As according to the instructions, I'm importing it like so:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '4.0.2'
}
```

However, when the build starts, I get the following error:

```
Plugin [id: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow', version: '4.0.2'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow:com.github.johnrengelman.shadow.gradle.plugin:4.0.2')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

When investigating the stack trace in configure build, I also find this:

```
org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/github/johnrengelman/shadow/com.github.johnrengelman.shadow.gradle.plugin/4.0.2/com.github.johnrengelman.shadow.gradle.plugin-4.0.2.pom'.

Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to plugins.gradle.org:443 [plugins.gradle.org/104.16.175.166, plugins.gradle.org/104.16.173.166, plugins.gradle.org/104.16.172.166, plugins.gradle.org/104.16.171.166, plugins.gradle.org/104.16.174.166] failed: Connection timed out: connect
```

Based on this, I'm assuming that there is something wrong between my machine and the plugins repository.  I'm working behind a corporate proxy, so I'm wondering if there is any workaround?

Edit:  Here is the structure for the code of my repository declaration. Due to security concerns, I'd rather not share the actual url:

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'corporate.repo.url.here:port' }
}
```

Upon double checking, it seems that the repository is correct, and so the plugin should be downloaded to my local Maven repository.  It was not, which I assume has to due with my migration to Gradle. Are there any settings in Gradle to handle this?

Comment: what does your `repositories` declaration look like?

Comment: I just edited the question to include that.  I can't put in actual URL used, but the structure is the same.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  In settings.gradle, I needed to set the repositories in pluginManagement to override the default behavior of gradle.

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'corporate.repo.url.here'
        }
    }
}
```

By default, gradle wants to go to `plugins.gradle.org`; however, I suspect that the proxy I'm working behind prevents that.  Hence, I need the code above to point it to the network repository.

Comment: worked for me - thanks a lot for pointing that out :) !